# How do you calculate interquartile range (IQR) correctly using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to understand the way to compute iqr (interquartile range).

according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228244/how-do-you-find-the-iqr-in-numpy), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472330/how-should-the-interquartile-range-be-calculated-in-python) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range), I tried 3 solutions to do this.

solution_1

```
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
q1_a = numpy.percentile(a, 25)
q3_a = numpy.percentile(a, 75)
q3_a - q1_a
```

solution_2

```
from scipy.stats import iqr
iqr(a)
```

solution_3

```
q1_am = np.median(numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
q3_am = np.median(numpy.array([4, 5, 6, 7]))
q3_am - q1_am
```

3 of them give the same result 3 which is correct.

when I tried another set of numbers, things were going weird.

both solution_1 and 2 output 0.95 which is not correct.

```
x = numpy.array([4.1, 6.2, 6.7, 7.1, 7.4, 7.4, 7.9, 8.1])
q1_x = numpy.percentile(x, 25)
q3_x = numpy.percentile(x, 75)
q3_x - q1_x
```

solution_3 gives 1.2 which is correct

```
q1_xm = np.median(np.array([4.1, 6.2, 6.7,7.25]))
q3_xm = np.median(np.array([7.25,7.4, 7.9, 8.1]))
q3_xm - q1_xm
```

What am I missing with the solutions?

any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get your expected result with [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#numpy-percentile) if you set `interpolation=midpoint`:

```
x = numpy.array([4.1, 6.2, 6.7, 7.1, 7.4, 7.4, 7.9, 8.1])
q1_x = numpy.percentile(x, 25, interpolation='midpoint')
q3_x = numpy.percentile(x, 75, interpolation='midpoint')
print(q3_x - q1_x)
```

This outputs:

```
1.2000000000000002
```

Setting `interpolation=midpoint` also makes [`scipy.stats.iqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html) give the result you wanted:

```
from scipy.stats import iqr

x = numpy.array([4.1, 6.2, 6.7, 7.1, 7.4, 7.4, 7.9, 8.1])
print(iqr(x, rng=(25,75), interpolation='midpoint'))
```

which outputs:

```
1.2000000000000002
```

See the `interpolation` parameter in the linked docs for more info on what the option actually does.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.quantile`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([4.1, 6.2, 6.7, 7.1, 7.4, 7.4, 7.9, 8.1])
q1_x = np.quantile(x, 0.25, interpolation='midpoint')
q3_x = np.quantile(x, 0.75, interpolation='midpoint')
print(q3_x - q1_x)
```

the output:

```
1.2000000000000002
```